# How to set the size of the window corresponding to the size of the it's background image?

Tags: c++, qt

Im am setting some image as main window's background (successfully) and trying to force to it size of the image but the result is some weird form. My code :

main.cpp

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QApplication>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();
        return a.exec();
    }
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap bkgnd("background.jpg");
    if (!bkgnd.isNull())
    {
        bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size() );
        QPalette palette;
        palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
        this->setPalette(palette);
        this->setMaximumSize (bkgnd.height (),bkgnd.width ());
        this->setMinimumSize (bkgnd.height (),bkgnd.width ());
}
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

But it's size still is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not clear what you want to do, the code is written meaningless

```
bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size() );
.....
this->setMaximumSize (bkgnd.height (),bkgnd.width ());
this->setMinimumSize (bkgnd.height (),bkgnd.width ());
```

here is a simple example , add enum [Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AspectRatioMode-enum)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap bkgnd("background.jpg");
    if (!bkgnd.isNull())
     {
       bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
       QPalette palette;
       palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
       this->setPalette(palette);
     }
}
```

or you can just use `css` `setStyleSheet`

```
setStyleSheet("background-image: url(background.jpg);");
```